# is there any solution to extract each value from a set?

Tags: java, input

This is my user input.

I have a simple command to ask for user input.

```
System.out.println("Enter 5 numbers:");
```

And this is what I will get from user input

```
{5,3,1,2,4}
```

Is there any way other than using `.charAt` to extract each value? Or is there a function that directly recognize this type of input and I can simply use a method to export the values?

Comment: How exactly are you reading the user input? As a `String`? Please provide the code sample, showing where you read the user input.

Comment: There are many ways to do that. One way involves a regexp.

Comment: @MauricePerry - https://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/  :-)

Comment: What I did is very troublesome and I somehow deleted.But my logic initially is I declare the input type as String and use .charAt() to access every index of the string.After that I set some if statements to store only digits to my array.I finding an alternative solution

Comment: @BrianAgnew alright: two regexps,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one solution (among many):

```
private static final Pattern RE = Pattern.compile(
        "\\{([0-9]+(?:,[0-9]+)*)\\}");

private static int[] parse(String input) {
    Matcher matcher = RE.matcher(input);
    if (!matcher.matches()) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid input: " + input);
    }
    String[] strings = matcher.group(1).split(",");
    int[] result = new int[strings.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < strings.length; ++i) {
        result[i] = Integer.parseInt(strings[i]);
    }
    return result;
}
```